# PC turning off immediately after turning on

Tags: windows, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer

After upgrading the motherboard to my PC, the PC won't boot. Immediately after turning it on, maybe one second, it turns right back off. After some research and another board & PSU with the same issue, I have found that after removing the 8-pin cpu connector it doesn't immediately turn off, though there is no video output. Any ideas on what is wrong with it? Using an intel system, no beep code, and have everything but the psu unplugged.

Comment: You try verify the power supply?

Comment: When you say, " After some research and another board & PSU with the same issue", do you mean you purchased a second new motherboard and a second new PSU?